# Does ngx-datatable pagination and header support tabindex for 508 compliance?

Tags: angular2-template, ngx-datatable

For the `<ngx-datatable-column>` html template, I want to add html attribute `tabindex` to support 508 but it is not working for me. Also the pagination can not hit enter or keyboard event to go to next page.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Name" tabindex="0">
    <ng-template></ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>`
```

Comment: What does support 508 mean?

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft It's a Government law requiring any government website/document/media to support a set of standards for accessibility. https://www.section508.gov/

Answer (score 1):

I think this does not work since there is no -element in the rendered DOM.

You could use templates instead to wrap each cell into something with a *tabindex* attribute.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
  <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
    <span tabindex="0">{{column.name}}</span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    <span tabindex="0">{{value}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-tab for an example.